# Does windows go to some low power mode when RDP connections is 'hidden/unfocused'?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I use RDP often, and I sometimes notice that when I switch to the RDP window only shortly every few minutes, it works slower than if I use it exclusively. Is it possible that some optimization causes the remote machine to work slower when it detects RDP is open but unused?

Thanks